# Smooth Scrolling + Button 'onclick' Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following js to implement smooth scrolling to page anchors within my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").on('click', function(event) {
            if (this.hash !== "") {
                event.preventDefault();
                var hash = this.hash;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function() {
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This works fine until I want to use buttons + links. For example, I have a button:

```
<button onclick="location.href='#anchor'" class="button">Name</button>
```

I tried playing around with the function above, like changing $("a")... to the a class or id in the button, i.e., $(".button")... but that doesn't do anything. Unfortunately my js knowledge ends there. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're changing the href immediately in the button.

Try this:

```
<button data-hash="anchor" class="button" type="button">Name</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.button").on('click', function(event) {
        var hash = $(this).data("hash");
        if (hash) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(document.getElementById(hash)).offset().top
            }, 800, function() {
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't seem to work. It actually made the button non-functional.

Comment: @DD1229 sorry I missed document.getElementById. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Set the target hash in the button. When it clicked, read it and move there

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function(event) {
    var hash = $(this).attr("data-target"),
      target = $("#" + hash);

    event.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      },
      800,
      function() {
        window.location.hash = hash;
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="section-0">Section 1</div>
  <button data-target="section-1">next</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-1">Section 2</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you say, "set the target hash in the button," what does that mean?

Comment: I mean this part `data-target="section-1"` on the button tag. @DD1229

Comment: Did you check the snippet? What's the problem? @DD1229